# Adding extra content to wp_mail 'message' segment

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I'm using a Custom Wordpress Template which is using the `wp_mail` Function.

So I have this code below, and the bolded portion is giving me problems:

wp_mail($et_email_to, sprintf( '[%s] ' . esc_html($_POST['et_contact_subject']), $et_site_name ), **esc_html($_POST['et_contact_message'])**,'From: "'. esc_html($_POST['et_contact_name']) .'" <' . esc_html($_POST['et_contact_email']) . '>');

I want to include extra stuff where the Message portion is. `esc_html($_POST['et_contact_message'])`

When I try to add anything extra there, it gives various PHP errors.

If I replace that `esc_html()` part with normal text like '12345', it works fine.

What I want to add to the end of my messages is this:

```
"IP Address: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."

Came From: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."

Browser: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

It works fine if I remove that `esc_html()` portion, but I can't get both to work together.

`esc_html()` works fine by itself also, it prints the Message from the Contact form.
I just can't get both things to work together.

These will fail for example:

```
esc_html($_POST['et_contact_message']) 12345,

esc_html($_POST['et_contact_message'] $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']),
```

etc...

Please help me out here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to make it work!
Here is the code:

```
$message = $_POST['et_contact_message'];
$message .= '

IP Address: ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$message .= '

Came From: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$message .= '

Browser: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
wp_mail($et_email_to, sprintf( '[%s] ' . esc_html($_POST['et_contact_subject']), $et_site_name ), $message,'From: "'. esc_html($_POST['et_contact_name']) .'" <' . esc_html($_POST['et_contact_email']) . '>');
```

Comment: It worked for you. I am trying to achieve similar to this one. But it is not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Check out string concatenation in PHP - there are many ways to do it, I'll highlight a few from http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

```
<?php
$foo = 'some';
$bar = 'baz';

$message = '';
$message .= 'Add ' . $foo;
$message .= ' variable to a string';

// You can do this all at once, in one line or many
$mesage = 'Add ' . $foo . ' variable to a string';

// Double-quotes are useful
$message = "Add {$foo} variable to a string";

// And there are other methods, like HEREDOC
$message = <<<TEXT
Add $foo variable to a string...in a HEREDOC



block.
TEXT;

// Some editors, like VIM, support syntax highlighting in HEREDOC
// Useful if you want to write out legeble code from other languages, like
// SQL.
$message = <<<SQL
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    col = %s
SQL;

$wpdb->prepare($message, $foo);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! I had actually found a solution a few minutes after I posted the question. (I spend hours trying before I posted the question). My solution looks quite similar to yours.